# Search filter order by function not working

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to implement ORDER BY feature in the following search function :

```
 public DataSet SearchTable()
    {

        string sql1 = "SELECT * from dbo.Documents1 order by Received_Date";

        bool flag = false;

        if (!txtRef.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            if (flag == false)
            {
                sql1 = sql1 + " where Ref LIKE N'%" + txtRef.Text + "%'";
                flag = true;

            }
            else
            {
                sql1 = sql1 + "  and Ref LIKE N'%" + txtRef.Text + "%'";
            }
        }

        if (!txtSubject.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            if (flag == false)
            {
                sql1 = sql1 + " where Subject LIKE N'%" + txtSubject.Text + "%'";
                flag = true;

            }
            else
            {
                sql1 = sql1 + "  and Subject LIKE N'%" + txtSubject.Text + "%'";
            }
        }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.
```

Any idea how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: btw. you could check empty string with string.IsNullOrEmpty http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx

Comment: Is it just me or this screams SQL Injection ... anyone ?

Comment: Rather than all of those repetitive flag checks, you could build up a list of conditions as separate strings, then (once they're all done) `string.Join` them with `" and "` as the separator and prefix a `"WHERE "`. You might also want to look into using parameters at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are Ordering By before the Where. This is not correct SQL syntax.

Try it the following way:

```
public DataSet SearchTable()
    {

        string sql1 = "SELECT * from dbo.Documents1";

        bool flag = false;

        if (!txtRef.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            if (flag == false)
            {
                sql1 = sql1 + " where Ref LIKE N'%" + txtRef.Text + "%'";
                flag = true;

            }
            else
            {
                sql1 = sql1 + "  and Ref LIKE N'%" + txtRef.Text + "%'";
            }
        }

        if (!txtSubject.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            if (flag == false)
            {
                sql1 = sql1 + " where Subject LIKE N'%" + txtSubject.Text + "%'";
                flag = true;

            }
            else
            {
                sql1 = sql1 + "  and Subject LIKE N'%" + txtSubject.Text + "%'";
            }
        }

        sql1 = sql1 + "  order by Received_Date";
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a separated method for returning the SQL Query. 
"Order By" clause is taken out and appended just before returning the query.
Also removed the 'else' condition from first block as its always going to be true.

```
public string GetSQL()
        {

            string sql1 = "SELECT * from dbo.Documents1";

            bool flag = false;

            if (!txtRef.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                sql1 = sql1 + " where Ref LIKE N'%" + txtRef.Text + "%'";
                flag = true;
            }

            if (!txtSubject.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                if (flag == false)
                {
                    sql1 = sql1 + " where Subject LIKE N'%" + txtSubject.Text + "%'";
                    flag = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    sql1 = sql1 + "  and Subject LIKE N'%" + txtSubject.Text + "%'";
                }
            }

            sql1 = sql1 + " order by Received_Date";

            return sql1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

In order to avoid that you should utilize [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) when possible. The code could then look like this:

```
    public DataSet SearchTable()
    {
        string sqlStatement = "SELECT * from dbo.Documents1";
        bool flag = false;

        var reference = "something"; // txtRef.Text
        var subject = "something else"; // txtSubject.Text

        var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(reference))
        {
            var referenceParameter = new SqlParameter("@referenceParam", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100) { Value = reference };
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(referenceParameter);
            sqlStatement += AddWhereLike("Ref", "@referenceParam", flag);
            flag = true;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subject))
        {
            var subjectParameter = new SqlParameter("@subjectParam", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100) { Value = reference };
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(subjectParameter);
            sqlStatement += AddWhereLike("Subject", "@subjectParam", flag);
            flag = true;
        }

        sqlStatement += " order by Received_Date";

        sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlStatement;

        // do your database reading here
    }

    private static string AddWhereLike(string columnName, string paramId, bool isFirstWhereCondition)
    {
        var whereCondition = isFirstWhereCondition ? " where " : " and " + columnName + "LIKE N'%" + paramId + "%' ";
        return whereCondition;
    }
```